# GroupManager/Essentials: No users can use the /help command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I'm in the user group owner. I have `- help` (4 spaces before the `-`) under every user group permissions in the groups.yml file. I logged into my server and it said "type /help for a list of commands." However, when I type /help (or when anyone does for that matter), it says, "You do not have access to this command."

Since that didn't work, in-game I used the command `/mangaddp <group> help`, adding the help command to every group that way. It said every group already had that permission when I did so. Still isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see your `world/groups.yml` and your `globalgroups.yml` files respectively?

Comment: Also, do you have a default group?

Comment: And are you sure everyone has the `bukkit.command.help` permission?

Comment: The permission should be `minecraft.command.help`, not just `help`.

Answer (score 1):

To bring all the comments together into an answer:

## First, but less important, Issue:

#### From **aytimothy**:

> Also, do you have a default group?

#### My note:

Default groups are what every person who is not specifically assigned to a group will be put in. If you don't have this, and you didn't move anyone into groups, this can cause issues

## Second, but more important, issue:

#### From aytimothy:

> And are you sure everyone has the `bukkit.command.help` permission?

#### From CommandFox

> The permission should be `minecraft.command.help`, not just `help`

#### My note:

The way your file is set up is incorrect. Permissions are not stored as commands, but as something like `plugin.subsection.permission`.

So, if you have Essentials, or some other plugin, use it's respective permission -- for Essentials, it's  `essentials.help`. If you don't you should use both Bukkit's `/help` permission, `bukkit.command.help`, and Minecraft's `/help` permission, `minecraft.command.help`.

#### Not required, but interesting, information:

The reason there are two (or three, if you have a plugin) different permissions for `/help` is because when you type `/help`, Minecraft will first look into the plugins for that command, then it will use it's own, and, if neither work, it will finally use Minecraft's.

This means that in terms of permissions, the heirarchy is like this:

`plugin.help` > if that fails > `bukkit.command.help` > if that fails > `minecraft.command.help` > if no permissions for any, it displays a permissions error to you.

#### More Permissions stuffs:

[Bukkit Permissions](http://wiki.bukkit.org/CraftBukkit_Commands)

[Using Permissions.yml](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Permissions.yml)

It is, however, recommended that you use a plugin for permissions rather than the native Bukkit perms system, and for this, I highly recommend [PermissionsEx](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/permissionsex/)